# How to rendering a Font-awesome css ions 5.14 in html without the javascript file

Tags: font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I have a old version of pro from a few years ago I purchased and now I am using.  So it is been a minute since using this.

page looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8" />
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
     <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
     <title></title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href='/css/all.min.css'>
     
  </head>
<body>

<i style="height:40px; width:40px" class="far fa-money-check-edit"></i>

<script type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

It shows the little square.  The CSS file is found (200 response) and I search through it and the icon is there in the css file when looking through the dev tools for the browser. If I include the all.js it shows up.  I thought the fontawesome css fonts didn't need javascript to work?  All documentation I read is that it is not needed.

What am I doing wrong or thinking wrong?

I am expecting that the icon displays in the browser with out the need of using javascript to do so.

Comment: The css file doesn't include any font file. If you're moving the css to a local directory you also need to copy the fontAwesome woff2 font file